# "WebDriverError: Unknown error" when using Selenium with Edge Chromium, Javascript bindings

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

When trying to run Selenium on Windows 10 Edge Chrome version 80, I am getting the following error:

```
Z:\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2626
        throw error;
        ^

WebDriverError: Unknown error
    at parseHttpResponse (Z:\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:536:11)
    at Z:\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
```

[...]

I am building it like this:

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    edge = require('selenium-webdriver/edge');

 var service = new edge.ServiceBuilder()
     .setPort(55555)
     .build();

 var options = new edge.Options();
 driver = edge.Driver.createSession(options, service);
```

Does anyone see why this might be happening? Has anyone had success building the driver using the javascript bindings and can share how they were able to do that?

I'm confident that I have the correct version of the Microsoft Edge Driver

Comment: Have you tried the chrome driver? As Edge is using the chromium engine

Comment: I haven't tried using the Chromedriver. It's not clear to me how I would go about doing that.

Comment: @Monofuse If you can provide the build code, and it works for me, I've got a bounty on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/* In another command prompt window enter the command:
   msedgedriver.exe --verbose  

   Then run the script as normal in the other command prompt
*/
const Selenium = require("selenium-webdriver");
const BROWSER_NAME = Selenium.Browser.EDGE;
const builder = new Selenium.Builder().forBrowser(BROWSER_NAME)
.withCapabilities({
        "browserName": 'MicrosoftEdge',
        "browserVersion": '81.0',
        "platformName": 'Windows 10',
        'ms:edgeChromium': true
    }).usingServer('http://localhost:9515')

const driver = builder.build()
```